# Property file path Eclipse vs Deployed Java Web App

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I'm maintaining properties files containing database credentials in protected folders on our internal server for each app that I deploy.  I'm not allowed to store the credentials within the WAR file.

When testing on my PC the path is a windows mount, but when I depoloy to the server it is a unix path

I have been handling the retreival as such

```
//siteDbCedentialFolder obtained from web.xml

Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = null;
try {
    //assume running on server first
      in = new FileInputStream("/abc/data/" + siteDbCedentialFolder + "/props.txt");
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
    // Probabaly Running locally
      in = new FileInputStream("W:/internal/abc/data/" + siteDbCedentialFolder + "/props.txt");
    } catch (Exception xx) {
    xx.printStackTrace();
    }
prop.load(in);
in.close();
```

is my approach to use a catch to get the local path OK or is there a better way to code this?

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to put the txt file in user home directory and get it by

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

and to get the full path

```
String pathToFile = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "props.txt";
```

It would work across all the platform, provided that you need to put the file at proper place (user home)

Comment: +1 but company has already dictated where the developers store the credentials.  Also this requires that I maintain two files.  One on server and one on developers machine.  My approach above uses just the one on the server.

Comment: just wondering if it is a good approach to use a try catch to programtically decide to use either the unix path or windows path. When app is run in Eclipse on my PC, a File Exception is thrown and then tries to get the path Windows style.